Continuity of distance to a convex set along a particular direction
Consider a compact, convex set $X \subseteq R^n$. Let $e = (1, 0, \dots, 0)\in R^n$ be a unit vector along a particular direction. Define a function $d: X \rightarrow R$ given by $d(x) = \max\{\alpha \ge 0 | x+\alpha\cdot e \in X\}$. Thus, $d(x)$ measures the distance along the direction $e$ of point $x$ from the boundary of $X$.
My question: Is $d$ continuous at all points $x\in X$?
I think the answer is yes and we need to use the convexity of $X$, but I am not able to prove it. Note that this does not follow from the standard result that the distance to a convex set is a continuous function either, as I am not looking at the minimum distance to $X$ but rather the distance along a particular direction, from within $X$. If $X$ is not convex, the answer is clearly no since there can be large 'jumps' in the distance along a direction. Would appreciate help on this!

You need to try simple examples first. Take $X={(0,0)} \cup \mathbb{R} \times (0,1]$, then $d((0,0) = 0$ but $d(0,t) = +\infty$ for $t \in (0,1]$.

Ok, I forgot to mention that $X$ is closed, bounded. Updated the question.

Come on, try a little harder. Modify the example I gave.

I don't know how to do that.

You need to try. Try a square, something. You need to do some work.
